# SwiftUI - Unable to set title on UIKit's NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I am working for a corporate and we have our own set of customised `UIKit` elements adapting to our brand guide which could be integrated using Cocoapods. I am just starting my first `SwiftUI` project and struggling to make use of our components from `CorporateKit` since they are built for `UIKit`.

We use the `NavigationController` from `CorporateKit` in `UIKit` project as below. `NavigationController` is created by just passing the `UIViewController` as input and it is set as `rootViewController` in `SceneDelegate`.

```
let navigationController = CorporateNavigationController(rootViewController: home)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

But, I couldn't able to use it directly in `SwiftUI` project. I went through "Interfacing with UIKit" topic and tried to implement the same for `CorporateNavigationController`.

```
import SwiftUI
import CorporateKit

struct CorporateNavigationStack: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CorporateKit.CorporateNavigationController {
        return CorporateNavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CorporateKit.CorporateNavigationController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    CorporateNavigationStack()
}
```

And in the `ContentView`,

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CorporateNavigationStack()
            .navigationTitle("Title")
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

I am trying to set title to the `NavigationController` and it is not set. I am not sure about what I miss here!

Comment: That's because you don't have `NavigationStack` or NavigationView` in ContentView?  Just chasing a wild goose...

Comment: You're also not correctly using the `navigationTitle` operator, it should be placed on the view controller from the stack, not on the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` (which I assume your `CorporateNavigationController` is a sublass of) finds its title from the `title` property of the `UIViewController` it's currently displaying.

So to get a title showing, you will need to set the title property like so:

```
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CorporateKit.CorporateNavigationController {
    let viewController = UIViewController()
    viewController.title = "This is the title"
    return CorporateNavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
}
```

The `.navigationTitle` modifier only works on SwiftUI `NavigationStack` or `NavigationView`. I would suggest using either UIKit (or CorporateKit in your case) or SwiftUI, and only mixing them when needed. That is, when using SwiftUI in an app and you can't make it in SwiftUI, leveraging `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to make a part in UIKit.